# How can I optimize this SQL query to run faster?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a following SQL query running on AWS RDS (Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible):

```
SELECT
    t,
    opening,
    MIN(low) as low,
    MAX(high) as high,
    SUM(low * volume) / NULLIF(SUM(volume), 0) AS aggr_low,
    SUM(high * volume) / NULLIF(SUM(volume), 0) AS aggr_high,
    closing,
    SUM(volume) as volume
FROM (
    SELECT 
        FIRST_VALUE(open) OVER (
            PARTITION BY timestamp - (timestamp % 180) ORDER BY timestamp, volume DESC
        ) AS opening,
        FIRST_VALUE(close) OVER (
             PARTITION BY timestamp - (timestamp % 180) ORDER BY timestamp DESC, volume DESC
        ) AS closing,
        low,
        high,
        volume,
        timestamp - (timestamp % 180) as t
    FROM candle
    WHERE pool_id IN (SELECT id FROM pool WHERE asset_1_id = 123 AND asset_2_id IS NULL)
    and type = "1M"
    and timestamp >= 0
    and timestamp < 99999999999999
) AS aggr
GROUP BY t, opening, closing
ORDER BY t;
```

How could I improve it? I am mostly interested in making it less costly for my DB server (and faster). What it is meant to do is to simply combine candles (timestamp, open, low, close, high, volume) that are saved periodically (every minute) together in order to make 3 minute candles (180 seconds) in this example. I run the following query, and then parse it to create candles like this:

```
for row in rows:
    (timestamp, open, low, high, aggr_low, aggr_high, close, volume) = row
    candles[timestamp] = {
        "open": open,
        "low": min(low if aggr_low is None else aggr_low, open, close),
        "high": max(high if aggr_high is None else aggr_high, open, close),
        "close": close,
        "volume": volume,
    }
```

It is by far the most run query in our application, so any improvement would be amazing. I will gladly explain further and any help is much appreciated.

This is my final iteration of the SQL query. Since I'm not an expert, I simply do not know how to improve it further.

Comment: Can you please provide the Query Plan? Put `EXPLAIN` before the `SELECT` and add the output to your Question.

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query, preferably after turning on track_io_timing.

Comment: It might help to change the input. I don't know the syntax of whatever language is being used here, but it'll be close to zero cost to add a 'group by' column to your input. In other words, add two counting variables, one that counts the rows, and the other counting up by 1 each time the first one goes up by 3. Then, append the second counter to each candle. Your query would then be `SELECT aggregate stuff FROM candle GROUP BY counterVariable`.